# How do I remove all text from my citations?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to remove all text from references in overleaf. Here is what I have right now -
"multi-headed dot-product attention Vaswani et al. [28]"

Here is what I'd like - "multi-headed dot-product attention [28]"

I am unable to understand why this happens, despite putting the style = numeric.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\bibliography{sample}

\title{Example}
\date{August 2021}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \textcite{adams1995hitchhiker}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see the output is Adams[1], whereas I'm looking for just [1].

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on, without seeing the actual code... Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: @DG' Thank you for your comment. I have made the changes. Please let me know if I can improve it anymore.

Comment: Don't mix `\bibliography` and `\addbibresource`. The latter is the correct way to add a database with `biblatex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `\textcite` which always prints the author. The biblatex manual states:

> `\textcite[〈prenote〉][〈postnote〉]{〈key〉}`
> `\Textcite[〈prenote〉][〈postnote〉]{〈key〉}`
>
> These citation commands are provided by all styles that come with this package. They are intended for use in the flow of text, replacing the subject of a sentence. They print the authors or editors followed by a citation label which is enclosed in parentheses. Depending on the citation style, the label may be a number, the year of publication, an abridged version of the title, or something else. The numeric and alphabetic styles use square brackets instead of parentheses.

The fix is simple: Use `\cite` instead.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%\bibliography{sample}

\title{Example}
\date{August 2021}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly
what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly
disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and
inexplicable.  There is another theory which states that this has
already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the
universe'' \cite{adams1995hitchhiker} % <----------

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]